# Firefox OS webapp <iframe> and callback

Tags: angularjs, iframe, firefox-os

How to embed the `iframe` tag in Firefox OS webapp?

I know about MozActivity. Is there any MozActivity for `<iframe>` tag handling and its callback handling?

I want to open another page URL in one page of a webapp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you would do it on any web page.

```
 <iframe src="http://some-other-webpage.com" />
```

Or from JS:

```
 var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
 iframe.src = 'http://some-other-webpage.com';
 document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```